# Unable to get the list in the fragments (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Why I am unable to get listview in the fragment. I have created the list along with the items. I have added items but unable to understand this. Please help me out to understand it. I have copied it and edited it.

Here's my code:

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
private ListView mListView;
private List<String> mNewsList;

public NewsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View frag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container,                                                                                                                             false);
    mListView = (ListView) frag.findViewById(R.id.MyListView);

    mNewsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");
    mNewsList.add("gjjggj");

 //   mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,mNewsList));
    mListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    return frag;

}
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNewsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mNewsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowview = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row,null);
        return rowview;
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You are just adding adapter to listview but no data resourcing are there is adapter..

```
mListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapters());
```

try to use arrayAdapter for data-source like String array

```
mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mNewsList));
```

and mNewsList should be String[].